# Метод самовывоз в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, в WordPress использую несколько методов доставки, два из них это самовывоз. При выборе самовывоза система все равно просит ввести адрес клиента. Можно ли как то это обойти и если можно, то как? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Без танцев с бубном не получиться. Пару готовых плагинов посмотрел - нет подобного функционала. В основном, если есть возможность задавать условия, то: "если пользователь", "если авторизован", "если сумма", "если товар"... условия по методу доставки не наткнулся. Только пару людей предлагают код.  Первая https://helpwp.ru/woocommerce/kak-skryt-polya-dostavki-dlya-samovyvoza.html ссылка, 
 вторая https://wpcommerce.ru/threads/kak-izbavitsja-ot-zapolnenija-vsex-polej-pri-samovyvoze.1077/ ссылка

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь, первая ссылка оказалась полностью рабочей! Мой гугл сломался)

Comment: Рад, что помог )))